# Where is the subject of the question ""How many people are in your family?"?

Tags: sentence-structure, questions

What is the subject of the question?

*"How many people are in your family?"*

What is the rule this question was formed with?
I mean, as I know, usually, to form a question with verb *to be* we have such a structure:

*Wh + To be (auxiliary) + subject + object ?*

I assume that subject in the question is *"family"*?

But what is the *"people"* then?

I am sure that the question is grammatically correct but just curious which rule does this question follow? Wanna find info on the internet to read about it, but dunno what to google. Is it a subject question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an exercise, where I had to order words to create a sentence, so that's what I came up with. I have no idea what is the other way to create a question, using only these words, so I am sure that I arranged the correct question, didn't I?

Comment: Maybe, 'How many people' is the subject. Compare to: "Three people are in your family". I'm not a native speaker though.

Comment: The subject is the noun phrase "how many people", in which "people" is the head and "how many" is a determinative phrase in which the interrogative adverb "how" is a modifier of the degree determinative "many". The predicate is the verb phrase "are in your family", where the preposition phrase "in your family" functions as complement of "are". Note that it would be more natural to say "How many people are there in your family?"

Answer (score 1):

How many people are in your family?

is really, in standard English:

How many people **are there** in your family?

**There are** six people in my family.

Proof of this fact is that, the answer to the question: How many people are in your family? cannot be: Six people are in my family. That is not idiomatic because a native speaker just wouldn't say that except in some limited circumstances, but  not in general when discussing how many members a family has.

Compare this question about the number of family members to a question about where people are:

How many people are in the garden? Ten people are in the garden.

"in the garden" is a location. For the "family" question ("How many people are in your family?", family is not a location. That's why it sounds funny to say: "Ten people are in my family." and it sounds natural to say: "There are ten people in my family".

***How many people*** is a noun phrase.

Alternative way to pose the question: How many family members do you have?

This pattern uses: There are, There is, and the question forms.

**There is** and **There are** are used as **existential clauses** to show the existence of something:

[existential clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause)

There in "There is" and "There are" is called a dummy subject. Another example: it. It is an interesting movie. "it" is a dummy subject.

Comment: I cannot agree that "How many people are in your family" is non-standard English. It is an ellipsis of "How many people are there in your family," but it is not a non-standard ellipsis.

Comment: @JeffMorrow If you accept "How many people are in your family?", you have to accept the correlative: "[number] people are in my family." I submit that: "There are 10 people in my family." is more standard. However, if I were a census taker, that would be a special circumstance, as I mentioned. In regular conversation, as a native speaker, I would never use it without the "there", either in the question or the answer. How many people are in the garden? In + the + place. A family is not a place. Generally speaking in English: people are in a place (or at, of course).

Comment: But I do accept that "ten people are in my family" is good English. It seems to me that you are confusing "frequent" with "standard." Please cite an authority that "ten people are in my family" is not grammatical.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I am not saying it is bad English. I'm saying it would only be used in certain special  circumstances and not in general everyday blah blah blah about how many family members one has. It's limited to certain contexts.

Comment: What you said is "'Six people are in my family' is not idiomatic." I simply think that is quite wrong, Nor do I think such a sentence may be used only in linited circumstances. Again, I ask for a citation from a reputable source that "there are" is a mandatory form in English.

Answer (score 0):

Your question follows *[How many](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/wh-question-words.htm) + **NOUN** + **VERB*** pattern.

> How many **people(NOUN)** **are(VERB)** in your family?

***How many people*** is the subject of the sentence asking the ***number*** of ***people*** *in your family*.

[image]
[Source](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=How%20many%20people%20are%20in%20your%20family%3F&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1)

**Clarification**: In the above image, **How many people** is labeled as **NOUN** as their standard; however, it is a **NOUN PHRASE** (a phrase being used as **NOUN**)!

In order to see whether the question was a "Wh + To be (auxiliary) + subject + object?", note that there is need of **there** in your sentence as follows, "How many people are **there** in your family?". Now see that "How many people are **there**?" would also be grammatical, however it would further create a question of **Where**. The "*in your family*" (prepositional) phrase answers **Where** and thence **family** is not the subject of the sentence.

Comment: "How many people" is not a noun, but a **noun phrase**". The complement is not "are in your family", but just "in your family". The labels 'pobj' and ADP make no sense.

Comment: @BillJ -1 "How many people" is not a noun, nor did I mention it to be. +1 You're right that the complement is not "are in your family", but just "in your family". +1 The label 'pobj' is indeed incorrect, that was simply a screenshot of SpaCy-dependency-tree parser. 0 ADP - adpositions (prepositions and postpositions), makes sense? ^^

Comment: Your diagram clearly has the word NOUN in orange for the NP "how many people".  Likewise for "your family", which is also am NP. It's a confusing diagram.

Comment: @BillJ The diagram surely confuses those who do not know how it works ^^ https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=How%20many%20people%20are%20in%20your%20family%3F&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1

Comment: @BillJ That is simply their standard to represent a noun phrase as NOUN in the dependency-tree; here is how the tree would look after I unchecked that "Merge Phrases" box https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=How%20many%20people%20are%20in%20your%20family%3F&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0

Comment: In that case it should say 'NP' to reflect the fact that it has a noun as head and one or more dependents. As shown in your answer, it is wrong, or at best misleading. A conventional tree diagram would be better.

Comment: @BillJ SpaCy is simply implying that the phrase is used as a NOUN (ie is a Noun Phrase of course since "Merge Phrases" is checked) if you unchecked the "Merged Phrases" you wont have any issues then.. The site simply shows you the dependencies of words and the POS of each word.. NOUN is a POS; NP isn't.

Comment: If that's not used as a NOUN (which it is and also as a SUB) then why do you wish SpaCy to label it NP and not NOUN? ^^

Comment: It is a noun (category), but it's used here as a subject (function). This is a crucial difference. Yes, noun is a word category and NP is its corresponding phrasal category. The point is that the diagram you presented is not helpful.

Comment: @BillJ How so? The diagram shows that the verb 'are' is depending upon the subject 'How many people', and as the label is 'nsub' that implies the phrase is being used as a subject of the sentence

Comment: A predicator (verb) is not a dependent in an NP. It is head of its own phrase, called a VP, which functions as predicate in the clause. Anyway, I'll leave it there, as I don't want to confuse you any more.

Comment: I messed up the dependency explanation.. sorry about that ^^ 'How many people' is depending upon the verb

Answer (score 0):

I am not native English speaker, so please take what I say with a bit of salt ;)

My logic would be that `people` is the subject. `How many` is an attribute of `people`. Similar with:

> Many people are in the family.
>
> 15 people are in the family.

`Many` and `15` are definitely not nouns - they just add extra information to the noun - quantity information in this case.

However, it is one of the more difficult grammar questions, I agree.

Comment: No, the subject is "how many people". "People" is the head of the noun phrase, and "how many" is an interrogative determiner.